# error while building project after importing a jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I imported a jar file to my project and it works now while I am in development, but whenever I try to build the project and create a patch it shows error "package xxx.xxx does not exist".

I used the this link to add the jar file to my project:   [How to import a jar file in Eclipse.](https://www.edureka.co/community/4028/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse)

I am using maven and here is the spring boot and jhipster versions of my project.

Spring Boot version:  2.4.4

JHipster version:  7.0.1

Comment: Please give more details about the error, edit your question and paste it as  text, explain which change exactly you made to your project. When you build, I suppose you use maven or gradle not the IDE?

Comment: I guess maven does not know about the jar file imported via eclipse, so building/packaging via maven does not work.